# Why displaying following a link do not work in some browsers?

Tags: html, redirect, header

When I put the following Link into any browser (Opera, IE, Firefox, Chrome) - the html request returns `error`.

http://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=showZvg&zvg_id=21056&land_abk=by

When I embed this link into a html document - a webpage is returns in every browser, except of Chrome.

I suppose this must be some header, which are set differently.
Which headers could it be?

Comment: maybe user-agent ? What do you mean by "embed" ?
to move forward, I would record the exact request in different browsers, and compare headers.

Comment: The `error` response comes from the server. It could be many headers that cause the problem, including the most obvious one: User-Agent. But without knowing the code that runs on the server, it'll be almost impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: By embed I mean creating a HTML document with a <a/> tag which points to the link.
It is not the user agent, since I managed to redirect correctly in all browsers, by using the webpage, where I got the link from.

Is there some place, where I can find documentation which headers are set when by different browsers? E.g. following an embedded link is different from entering it into address bar